How to remove a hooked function from woocommerce_email_order_meta hook
I need to include custom data in an email for a WooCommerce site, namely, delivery date and time.
I have tried to override the existing hook "woocommerce_email_order_meta" using this code, I've temporarily written it in functions.php before moving to plugin file when it's working.
remove_action('woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 10, 4);

add_action('woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'custom_email_order_meta', 10, 4);

function custom_email_order_meta($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email) {
    echo "Custom Text: This is my custom text.\n";
}

When I test the email, the custom text line is printed. However, the original content of the WC Hook is also printed underneath.
Is there any way to completely override the WC hook, do I have to try and create a new one? If I create a new one, will it be listed in the email editor, so I can drop in the hook?

ive also found this resource but it hasn't helped as of yet, am i removing the wrong hook  in the remove action line?https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-emails/

You can try two different things, replacing this line from your code (which is not correct):
remove_action('woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 10, 4);


With this (the best way):

add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', '__return_empty_array', 9000, 1);


Or with this (the working alternative to your code attempt):

remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', array( WC()->mailer, 'order_meta' ), 10, 3 );

Both should work.

Addition:
The woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields filter hook can also allow filtering which metadata you want to display, using a custom hooked function, like in the following example:
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'filter_email_order_meta_fields', 9000, 3);
function filter_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
        if ( $field['label'] === __('Some label', 'woocommerce') ) {
            unset($fields[$key]); // Remove specific meta data
        }
    }

    return $fields;
}

